# What is the best way of accessing dialog controls from within inner classes?

Tags: java, android

How do I access the activity instance from within a nested onclicklistener within an adapterview? I have tried all sorts of things (context/ getcontext()) but they do not work. I am having the issue in the check permission if statement below.

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.delegate_access_listview_item, parent, false);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Delegate");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_deleagte_access_profile);

            final Button callBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
            //callBtn.setText();

            Button emailBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
            //emailBtn.setText();

            CircularImageView imgView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            // TODO: set image drawable

            dialog.show();

            callBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

                    if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                context,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                                REQUEST_CALL);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("373548474"));
                        context.startActivity(callIntent);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you should implement. Try the steps mentioned below:

1) Set on click listener in onCreateViewHolder, as you have done.

2) When onClick event is triggered, instead of implementing the dialog here, send a callback to the activity.

3) When the callback is invoked in activity show the dialog.

In this way, you'll have the activity access plus a clean code

Answer (score 0):

Please create the Application Class of your root source folder and add on the AndroidManifest.xml file.

ApplicationClass.java

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
    private static ApplicationClass getInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized ApplicationClass getInstance() {
        return getInstance;
    }
    public static Context getContext() {
        return getInstance;
    }
 }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
```

AdapterClass.java

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.delegate_access_listview_item, parent, false);

v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ApplicationClass.getInstance());
        dialog.setTitle("Delegate");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_deleagte_access_profile);

        final Button callBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
        //callBtn.setText();

        Button emailBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
        //emailBtn.setText();

        CircularImageView imgView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        // TODO: set image drawable

        dialog.show();

        callBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ApplicationClass.getInstance(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

                if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                            REQUEST_CALL);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("373548474"));
                    context.startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

return new MyViewHolder(v);
}
```